# How to save date values ​as well when saving values ​using pandas library?

Tags: python, pandas

When the result value is saved in a spreadsheet using the pandas library, the date date value is not displayed.
I want the date values ​​in the date to be stored in the spreadsheet as well

```
import pandas as pd
import pygsheets
import FinanceDataReader as fdr

gc = pygsheets.authorize(outh_file="/config/workspace/client_secret.json")
file_nm = "stock"
sh = gc.open(file_nm)

tiker_list = ['FNGU', 'NAIL',  'SOXL', 'LABU', 'DFEN', 'TPOR', 'TQQQ']
df_list = [fdr.DataReader(ticker, '2021-01-01')['Close'] for ticker in tiker_list]

df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
df.columns = ['FNGU', 'NAIL',  'SOXL', 'LABU', 'DFEN', 'TPOR', 'TQQQ']

wks = sh[16]
wks.set_dataframe(df,(3,2))
```

[image]

Comment: What date value? How does the dataframe look like? Is the date in the dataframe before you save it? What dtypes do you use?

Comment: Hi! You should add that to the answer and not as a comment, @rootenchoi :)

Comment: Could you properlly add your table in a nice format? and at least a screenShot insetaed of a picture?